# find version of jquery_ujs used in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ujs

How can I find the current version of jquery_ujs used in my rails application?

I have included it by gem 'jquery-rails'. version of jquery-rails gem is 2.1.4 and Rails version is `3.2.14`.

Comment: I need to compare this version with the version listed here https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: You can try calling `Jquery::Rails::JQUERY_UJS_VERSION` from the rails console.

Comment: @Sharagoz Thanx for the reply... There is one issuee, It returns `bddff6a677edc54f00e48bde740b0b22d68deef6` which is not in the list of  jquery ujs- Changelog

Comment: Googling that hash takes us to a commit done in a fork and not the master repo. https://github.com/lycan785/jquery-ujs/commit/bddff6a677edc54f00e48bde740b0b22d68deef6 They're not too good at keeping track of their versions it seems, hehe.

Comment: *whew* that clears my doubts... Again Thanx Sharagoz for helping me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Sharagoz for pointing this out

> You can try calling Jquery::Rails::JQUERY_UJS_VERSION from the rails
>   console.

It return the version of `jquery_ujs` used in current rails project.